# How to list all managed objects in heap in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

is it possible to list all objects stored in heap.
I would like to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<GCHandle> listOfObjectsInHeap = GetListOfObjectsFromHeap();
```

Comment: why do you want to do this?  what do you want to do with this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to achieve this. Unfortunately not in managed code.

Answer (score 6):

Using the ClrMD library you can connect to your own process and inspect the heap.

However, using ClrMD against a running process is known to limit the information available as the heap may be changing as you're trying to walk it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx

Comment: This is the best way to do.

Comment: And the link is now "Forbidden"

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any managed function that allows you to do this. You could retrieve this information using the [HeapWalk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366710(v=VS.85).aspx) function. [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee175819(v=VS.85).aspx) of using it (it creates a new heap but you could retrieve the current process heap with [GetProcessHeap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366569(v=VS.85).aspx)).