# How can I get the list of live objects in c#?

Tags: c#, object, live, creation

I want to get the list of live objects defined in my application.

By live objects, I mean every objects created.

For example, let's say there are controls object created in some part of an application and I want to access a particular one by name.

Or I would want to access some private object in some public class where I have no "starting" point of access to the public class object.

There must be a way since it's what a debugger does essentially.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want this functionality for?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934392/how-to-list-all-managed-objects-in-heap-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an easy task. I think the closest is the [Profiler API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736845/is-is-possible-to-use-profiling-api-right-from-c). This [is another site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/) that is a good reference for profiling API.